# I am getting this message - Could not save as ... because write access was not granted

Tags: macbook-pro

I am getting this message in PS CC. I normally use a PC for all of my editing but my PC is down, so I am using a MAC. This is so foreign to me. I am trying to save a file that I imported in LR.

Comment: Is your mac running mac os x sierra?

Comment: If you opened the file directly from some media it maybe read only or saving it to the same may cause this message try coping it to the desktop and saving it to the same

Answer (score 1):

That sounds to me like a file permissions issue:

1. Check if the file you are trying to open in Photoshop is currently open anywhere else (ie. another program is using it, hence locking write access).
2. Right-click the file in Finder and check if your user account has full access privileges to manipulate the file, if not, add them

Hopefully those two hints may get you closer to your desired outcome. Let me know how you get on.